# MQTT cannot be resolved in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

I am learning about MQTT protocol and I run this code I found on Google:

```
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence;

public class MQTT {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String topic        = "MQTT Examples";
        String content      = "Message from MqttPublishSample";
        int qos             = 2;
        String broker       = "tcp://iot.eclipse.org:1883";
        String clientId     = "JavaSample";
        MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();

        try {
            MqttClient sampleClient = new MqttClient(broker, clientId, persistence);
            MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
            connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
            System.out.println("Connecting to broker: "+broker);
            sampleClient.connect(connOpts);
            System.out.println("Connected");
            System.out.println("Publishing message: "+content);
            MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(content.getBytes());
            message.setQos(qos);
            sampleClient.publish(topic, message);
            System.out.println("Message published");
            sampleClient.disconnect();
            System.out.println("Disconnected");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch(MqttException me) {
            System.out.println("reason "+me.getReasonCode());
            System.out.println("msg "+me.getMessage());
            System.out.println("loc "+me.getLocalizedMessage());
            System.out.println("cause "+me.getCause());
            System.out.println("excep "+me);
            me.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But when i run it on ECLIPSE IDE, some error appear:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAxxB.jpg)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    MemoryPersistence cannot be resolved to a type
    MemoryPersistence cannot be resolved to a type
    MqttClient cannot be resolved to a type
    MqttClient cannot be resolved to a type
    MqttConnectOptions cannot be resolved to a type
    MqttConnectOptions cannot be resolved to a type
    MqttMessage cannot be resolved to a type
    MqttMessage cannot be resolved to a type
    MqttException cannot be resolved to a type

    at MQTT.main(MQTT.java:16)
```

I don't understand why I have these error.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that eclipse can not find the Paho MQTT classes. This is most likely because you have not added the jar file containing those classes to your classpath.

Given the way you have asked the question I'm going to guess that you haven't even downloaded the required jar file from the paho site.

Details on downloading the src or building with maven can be found on the Paho site [here](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/)